# cards.dll not found, but it's there

Tags: windows-10, gaming, dll

Dad wants to play the games that came with Windows XP (Minesweeper, Hearts, Solitaire, FreeCell and Spider), but he doesn't really like any more modern iterations (I mean, have you seen the fancy graphics Minesweeper has now? I don't think he's wrong. Also, there's ads.)

Under Windows 8.1, I solved this problem by copying the old executables from XP in the Windows\System32 folder, along with a file called cards.dll, and it worked fine.

I di the same thing under Windows 10 on his new PC and MSHearts fails silently, while Sol and FreeCell tell me that CARDS.dll is missing (and yes, I have tried renaming the file to uppercase, to no avail). I repeat, the file is already there and all the executables are in the same folder.

What am I supposed to do to make those games work properly?

Comment: It is entirely possible that the dll in question uses some Window XP libraries or features that are no longer present in Windows 10 and that the "dll failed to load" error is handled by the same "dll missing" routine in those programs. What is wrong with all the Windows Store versions of those programs such as Microsoft Solitaire and so on?

Comment: @Mokubai ads, having to link to your MS account or getting redirected to their page at every access, fancy distracting graphics, a completely different feel. Luckily I'm seeing also "classic" version of those games, I hope dad will like them.

Comment: If you cannot run them on Windows 10 you will have to use a virtual machine.  I suspect you have just encountered an incompatibility with Windows 10

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why they give a missing .dll error when placed in the System32 folder; it does for me as well. If you place them in a different folder, they will work.

1. Make a new folder "C:\Program Files\Games"
2. Place the .exe and .dll files in this directory
3. Make a shortcut to the .exe files